# Do skill points have to be done by one player only?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one

I finished the game and i'm now trying to get all of the skill points. I played most of this game with another person. There's some skills that want you to kill X ennemis with the weapon Y.

My question is: if I don't really play with weapon Y, but my friend does, is it better if he continues to kill enemies, or can I continue adding kills to the counter by using the same weapon.

In other words, if the skill point requirement is to kill 100 ennemies, and I know my friend has killed at least 50 (because he has been awarded the "50 kills" skill), is it better if he continues using this weapon? If I never played with this weapon, do I have to kill 50 enemies to get this skill point or I need to kill 100 of them?

*Assume the upgrades on the weapon are the same for both of us.

Comment: Did you get the 50 kills achievement as well? If so, then it would seem your friend's kills count toward your own achievement(s), otherwise I'd have to say no.

Comment: I succeeded some achievement, but I rarely play alone. So it's hard for me to count the number of enemies I kill. Also, I do not know how many victims my friends have done before with the other characters.